# Class cast exception, Trouble animating the button from one layout to another

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, classcastexception

i want to move the button from top corner to bottom right corner (from one layout to another), the transition works perfectly when i use only one layout i.e relative layout.
the logic is: when i click on the top linear layout the button should move to the 2nd (bottom) linear layout. But i am facing this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

my java code is:

```
private void MoveBTN() {
//transition
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(myLayout);
// View myBtn=findViewById(R.id.btn1);
//moveing button
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams LP=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
LP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
myButton1.setLayoutParams(LP);
//resizing button
ViewGroup.LayoutParams size=myButton1.getLayoutParams();
size.height=71;
size.width=65;
myButton1.setLayoutParams(size);
}
```

my layout is given in the picture[my Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLQhl.jpg)

Comment: this is not possible to move the viewItem from one view to another. You can move this within same view

Comment: so what shoud one do if he has to move from one layout to another? is there any other method???

Comment: create two views and make one visible and other invisible when required

Answer (score 1):

Your button is inside LinearLayout. So casting RealativeLAyout.Params will throw exception. Try changing layout params not of the button, but of the layout it is in

Comment: i have tried this

 LinearLayout.LayoutParams LP=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

but now the compiler is not giveing me the option for adding rules and also how will the compiler get to know that of which linear layout param i am using? because here i have two linear layouts.